# Open Menu is not working in Mobile view

Tags: mobile, responsive

my website is www.ukikomerc.com and my open menu is not working in mobile view. I already try to deactivate plugins but still, I have the same problem. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Did you contact the theme's support? They should be able to help you out as it seems to be an issue with the theme.